# Sort dictionary of dictionaries by value

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt

I have this dictionary:

```
statuses = {
            'pending' : {'status_for':'all', 'position':1},
            'cancelled' : {'status_for':'all','position':2},
            'approved' : {'status_for':'owner', 'position':1},
            'rejected - owner' : {'status_for':'owner', 'position':2},
            'accepted' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':1},
            'rejected - developer' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':3},
            'closed' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':5},
            }
```

I've also got a function to pull all `status_for` values of either `owner` or `dev` that looks like this and put it into a PyQt QComboBox:

```
for s in statuses:
            if statuses[s]['status_for'] == "dev" or statuses[s]['status_for'] == "all":
                cb_developer_status.addItem(s.capitalize(), s)
```

I'd like to order these by the `position` value though. What is a good way to do this, so that when I populate by combobox I have it in a predefined order?

I realize that the snippet above is checking for both 'dev' and 'all', my assumption right now is that I'd have to loop through the dictionary twice to get the two separate blocks in the order I wish (ie. 'all' appears before 'dev').

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value), but I'm not sure how to convert this answer to something that 
is a dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Would something like this work? Similar to the post you linked, this uses the `key` function of `sorted` to provide a custom sort order. `iteritems()` returns a `(key, value)` tuple, so that gets passed into `lambda (x, y): y['position']`, where `y['position']` is the value (your nested dictionary, keyed by the status), and `position` is the item by which you want to sort.

```
In [35]: statuses = {
            'pending' : {'status_for':'all', 'position':1},
            'cancelled' : {'status_for':'all','position':2},
            'approved' : {'status_for':'owner', 'position':1},
            'rejected - owner' : {'status_for':'owner', 'position':2},
            'accepted' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':1},
            'rejected - developer' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':3},
            'closed' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':5},
            }

In [44]: for s in sorted(statuses.iteritems(), key=lambda (x, y): y['position']):
   ....:     print s
   ....:
   ....:
('accepted', {'position': 1, 'status_for': 'dev'})
('approved', {'position': 1, 'status_for': 'owner'})
('pending', {'position': 1, 'status_for': 'all'})
('rejected - owner', {'position': 2, 'status_for': 'owner'})
('cancelled', {'position': 2, 'status_for': 'all'})
('rejected - developer', {'position': 3, 'status_for': 'dev'})
('closed', {'position': 5, 'status_for': 'dev'})
```

Comment: `key=lambda (k,v): v['position']` is a bit easier on the eyes +1

Comment: @JonClements Can't argue with that :) Changed.

Comment: Note that in python 3, `key=lambda(k,v): v['position']` must be written as `key=lambda k_v: k_v[1]['position']`

Comment: And `dict.iteritems()` is in python3 `dict.items()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems-when-trying-to-use-networkx

Comment: Both of you are right. Just tested successfully in *python3* `sorted(statuses.items(), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1]['position'])`

Answer (score 11):

```
In [232]: statuses = {                                                                  
            'pending' : {'status_for':'all', 'position':1},
            'cancelled' : {'status_for':'all','position':2},
            'approved' : {'status_for':'owner', 'position':1},
            'rejected - owner' : {'status_for':'owner', 'position':2},
            'accepted' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':1},
            'rejected - developer' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':3},
            'closed' : {'status_for':'dev', 'position':5},
            }

In [235]: sorted(statuses,key=lambda x:statuses[x]['position'])
Out[235]: 
['accepted',
 'approved',
 'pending',
 'rejected - owner',
 'cancelled',
 'rejected - developer',
 'closed']
```

or using `operator.getitem()`:

```
In [260]: from operator import *

In [261]: sorted(statuses.items(),key=lambda x:getitem(x[1],'position'))
Out[261]: 
[('accepted', {'position': 1, 'status_for': 'dev'}),
 ('approved', {'position': 1, 'status_for': 'owner'}),
 ('pending', {'position': 1, 'status_for': 'all'}),
 ('rejected - owner', {'position': 2, 'status_for': 'owner'}),
 ('cancelled', {'position': 2, 'status_for': 'all'}),
 ('rejected - developer', {'position': 3, 'status_for': 'dev'}),
 ('closed', {'position': 5, 'status_for': 'dev'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old now to answer, but I ran in a similar problem with almost the same dictionary structure you have, and this how I solved it,

I have structure like this:

```
dictOfDicts = {
   0: {'id': 3, 'title': 'hello'}, 
   1: {'id': 1, 'title': 'hi'},
   2: {'id': 2, 'title': 'aloha'},
}
```

and I wanted to order it to be like this:

```
dictOfDicts = {
   0: {'id': 1, 'title': 'hi'}, 
   1: {'id': 2, 'title': 'aloha'}
   2: {'id': 3, 'title': 'hello'},
}
```

i.e to change the outer items to be ordered by using inner `'id'` items.

---

So I first got the new index in a list for the outer items by using `sorted()`:

```
newIndex = sorted(dictOfDicts, key=lambda x: dictOfDicts[x]['id'])
```

now `newIndex` has the new order in a list

```
#output
newIndex = [1,2,0]
```

then I used this to change the order for the outer items using `newIndex`:

```
dictOfDicts = {newIndex[k]: dictOfDicts[k] for k in newIndex}
```

If anyone wants to know what exactly happened just tell me in the comments, I don't want the answer to be longer than necessary since the question got answered already.

Comment: Adding to this answer, if the keys of your parent dictionary are strings as opposed to integers, then you would want to use this line when rebuilding your dictionary in the right order:
dictOfDicts = {k: dictOfDicts[k] for k in newIndex}

This is because you can't slice lists on strings (the newIndex variable is a list).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another best way to sort python dict of dict (dictionary of dictionary):

```
# define dictionary data
dictOfDict = {
    'mainkey1': {'subkey1':'a', 'subkey2': 100},
    'mainkey2': {'subkey1':'b', 'subkey2': 50},
    'mainkey3': {'subkey1':'c', 'subkey2': 500},
    'mainkey4': {'subkey1':'d', 'subkey2': 250}
}

# define another dictionary to store sorted dictionary data
sorted_dictOfDict = dict()

# sort mainkeys by subkey2 :: outputs a list of mainkeys from original dict
sorted_keys = sorted(dictOfDict, key=lambda x:dictOfDict[x]['subkey2'], reverse=False)

# use the sorted list of keys to copy original dict to sorted dict (key-val by key-val)
for key in sorted_keys:
    sorted_dictOfDict[key] = dictOfDict[key]

# clear original dict and copy sorted dict back to original
dictOfDict.clear()
dictOfDict = sorted_dictOfDict.copy()

print(dictOfDict)
```

Output:

```
dictOfDict = {
    'mainkey2': {'subkey1':'b', 'subkey2': 50},
    'mainkey1': {'subkey1':'a', 'subkey2': 100},
    'mainkey4': {'subkey1':'d', 'subkey2': 250},
    'mainkey3': {'subkey1':'c', 'subkey2': 500}
}
```