# how to print a dictionary sorted by a value of a subdictionary?

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I have a dictionary inside a dictionary and I wish to print the whole dictionary but sorted around a value in the sub dictionary

```
Lesson = {Name:{'Rating':Rating, 'Desc':Desc, 'TimeLeftTask':Timeleft}}
```

or

```
Lesson = {'Math':{'Rating':11, 'Desc':'Exercises 14 and 19 page 157', 'TimeLeftTask':7}, 'English':{'Rating':23, 'Desc':'Exercise 5 page 204', 'TimeLeftTask':2}}
```

I want to print this dict for example but sorted by 'Rating' (high numbers at the top)
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573123/sort-dictionary-of-dictionaries-by-value) post but i don't fully understand it. 
If you could keep it simple it would be great.
And yes i'm making a program to sort and deal with my homework
Thanks in advance

Comment: The question you linked to answers your question. Have you tried applying it to your dict? What don't you understand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort dictionary of dictionaries by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573123/sort-dictionary-of-dictionaries-by-value)

Comment: The problem is, that it gives me a syntax error and, because i don't unerstand what i'm doing, i can't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sort_by_subdict(dictionary, subdict_key):
    return sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1][subdict_key])

Lesson = {'Math':{'Rating':11, 'Desc':'Exercises 14 and 19 page 157', 'TimeLeftTask':7}, 'English':{'Rating':23, 'Desc':'Exercise 5 page 204', 'TimeLeftTask':2}}
print(sort_by_subdict(Lesson, 'Rating'))
```

As there is no notion of order in [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), we need to represent the dictionary as a list of key, value pair tuples to preserve the sorted order.

The [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573123/sort-dictionary-of-dictionaries-by-value) you mention sorts the dictionary using the [sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) function such that it returns a list of `(k, v)` tuples (here `k` means key & `v` means value) of top level dictionary, sorting by the desired value of sub dictionary `v`.

Comment: When i do that i get invalid syntax. I'm on python 3.4 btw the error is on sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): v[key_in_values]), more specificaly on key=lambda here -->(<--  k, v) on that parenthesis

Comment: @TheD0ubleT You have to do it like this in Python 3: `key=lambda k_v: k_v[1][key_in_values]`

Comment: I'm getting this  
line 148, in <lambda>
    return sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1][key_in_values])
NameError: name 'key_in_values' is not defined

Comment: @TheD0ubleT, I've ported the code in my answer to python3 & is tested on python 3.4. Moreover, the NameError must have been thrown because the name `key_in_values` is changed to `subdict_key`. :-)

Comment: Last thing, it's arranged from lowest to highest (ascending order), i'd like it to be in decending order, is it possible?

Comment: Just pass an additional argument `reverse=True` to the function `sorted`.